# Is single sign on the only way to achieve this user experience?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, single-sign-on

Given:

So let's say I have a Ruby on Rails Web Application A on one domain (www.aaa.com) which contains User information (email, password, name).  I want to use Java Web Application B (over at www.bbb.com), a search tool which contains information about a user's political campaigns and can expose its searching capabilities via an API (e.g., api.bbb.com/search?query=Jose), and integrate its searching capabilities. B does not contain user information (though let's assume you can do a create action on B to create a user when they are "activated" as a valid user in A). A is a product by one company and B is a software product by another.

Requirements:

I would like the search results to be displayed on a web page served by Web Application A and the casual user to never know that they are using Application B in any way. I of course want to make sure it's an authenticated user on the Application B side that is accessing its search capabilities.

What are my options for securely authenticating an Application A user on both A and B such that it can use Application B's resources?  I would say OAuth might be a good solution but I want to make the user experience seamless - they should not know they are accessing B's resources, so having them login on B and redirect back to A won't meet the requirements (as I understand the OAuth flow).

Comment: Does Application B have an API which you can query then display the results yourself from Application A?

Comment: @TarynEast, yes it does.

Comment: Then that might be the way to go... use Application A to store B's credentials and query B behind the scenes for data, then render it however you like.